# How can i use "if" and "text" as a reader to a condition to formatting a text on the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to know if, within Excel I can combine the functions "if" and "text" to create a condition that reads the information from a cell, to paste the formatting in another one.
Example:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13996842215 | cell phone |
| 2 | 1334665909 | home phone |

when the phone number is a cell phone, format cell A1 from "13996842215" to "(13) 99684-2215"
when the phone number is home phone, format cell A2 from "1334665909" to "(13) 3466-5909"

```
=if(LOCATE("*Notebook*";A2)>0;"Computers") (this one grabbed from the internet)
```

```
=IF(G30="";"(##) ####-####")
```

```
=IF(LOCATE(home phone;a1;)>0;TEXT(a2;'(##) ####-####))
```

```
=if(A1 = "home phone";(text(A2; '(##) ####-####)))
```

Comment: =SE(NÚM.CARACT(f16)>10; TEXTO(f16; '(##) ####-####);TEXTO(f16; '(##) #####-####))
i also try this

Comment: Those will change the format in another cell.  It will not change the format in the reference cell.  And the formula would be: `=IF(B1 = "cell phone";TEXT(A1;"(##) ####-####"),TEXT(A1;"(##) #####-####")` or `=TEXT(A1;IF(B1 = "cell phone";"(##) ####-####","(##) #####-####"))`